# Android: issue with drag&drop in horizontalscrollview

Tags: android, animation, drag-and-drop

I have a **container view**, called A. I want to exchange 2 views: X,Y by drag&drop + animation

X is outside the scrollview, Y is inside L, L inside the scrollview:

X

Y Y Y Y Y Y

My goal is: drag Y to X position and drop, Y will fly to X and X will fly to Y. Simple!

I do by this way:

> 1. A.removeView(X)
> 2. Set new postion for X
> 3. L.addView(X)
> 4. //do animations...
> 5. Do the same thing for Y

After a nice animation, I see everything is so good, X,Y exchange its position. But when I scroll view L, **I didn't see X attached to L** (like X and L is different layers...)

Anyone know this please help me. Thanks!